# Show/hide layers in PDF file on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, pdf

I have a PDF file that contains several groups or layers of vector objects. When I open the document in Illustrator, these groups are listed in the layers panel. What I am trying to do is recreate in C/Obj-C code (on iOS) the possibility of showing and hiding each layer. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Then what is this?: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7c5e.w.html